# Media transfer in webrtc with TURN relay

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

Suppose A want to communicate with B

By sending Allocate request to turn server T1 , A get the relay address and port as R1:r1

Similarly, B sending Allocate request to turn server T2, B get the relay address and port as R2:r2

Now A want to send media to B, then A send media to R1:r1, with R2:r2 as the destination address, when turn server receives the  media at R2:r2, it forward to B. is the media transfer in webrtc, forwarded in this way or not?

If A don't know the B's relayed transport address, then How can A reaches B?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is exactly how it works if you use TURN relay.

If A and B want to connect with each other, they must know **each others** server reflexive or relay address. This applies if A and B are in separate networks. Server reflexive address is NATs public address which is gathered through STUN server. If they don't know any of these two addresses then they can't connect with each other.

If A doesn't know B's relayed transport address then they can connect through server reflexive address.

Even knowing only server reflexive address of each other won't guarantee connection establishment. If one of A or B is behind symmetric NAT and other is behind Symmetric/PRC NAT then A and B must know the turn relay address of each other to guarantee connection establishment.